# Setup Latest django code on local machine to learn and develop?

Tags: django

I want to know how can i setup django code(forked from github or any) on my local machine ?
I am not taking about installing it. I am talking about to work as a developer
on django code itself. My whole aim is to learn django even more better and 
improve myself.I want to know how the automatic admin is built , etc.

How exactly i can run it on my ubuntu system ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can [clone the repository](https://github.com/django/django), if you have [git installed](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git):

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/django/django.git
   $ cd django
   django $ ls
   ```
2. You can create a [virtual environment](http://www.virtualenv.org/), install django in it and the play with the local copy:

   ```
   $ virtualenv ~/my_django
   $ source ~/my_django/bin/activate
   (my_django) $ pip install django
   ```
3. The easiest option is to simply [browse the source online](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django) if all you want to know is how something is put together.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it, you'll have the entire code available somewhere like `/usr/lib/python/site-packages/django` (use `locate django` in terminal to find the correct dir) on Linux or `C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django` on Windows.

You can see the code, and even make modifications. If you want to contribute to Django, you'll need some knowledge before, and [follow some rules](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/).

Comment: Hi Maxime ! I just want to clear myself more. Let say i  modified some code of django where my site-packages are , then where i can see it. You mean i need to run the poll tutorials and don't touch its code but need to modify django code and see if the modifcations are appearing on poll website . Am i correct ?

Comment: Create a simple project ;) It's a framework, you need to use it like if you're a user to test your modifications somehow.